# Why jsonp is disabled by default in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, wms, json

> JSONP     EXCEPTIONS=text/javascript  Return a JsonP in the form: paddingOutput(...jsonp...). See WMS vendor parameters to change the callback name. Note that this format is disabled by default.

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html

**Is there any security, performance or vulnability issues with jsonp enabled?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discussion suggests that the risk is real but minor http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GSIP-79-Json-support-and-WFS-and-WMS-ExceptionHandler-s-tt4999973.html#a5000874